# npm script runs fine in the terminal when typed manually but not through package.json file

Tags: npm, babeljs, node-modules, package.json, npm-scripts

I have been trying to convert my `.js` file into brower supported using babel. For this i have installed some babel packages and tried to put the script in the "scripts" object in package.json file. The interesting thing is that when i run the same script in the terminal itself it is working fine. But when i run this using `npm run babel_script` it doesn't & gives the error: `'node_modules' is not recognized as internal or external command.`

here's my package.json file :
[image]

this is the error or problem :
[image]

This is my folder structure in case of some directory issue :

[image]

Any idea how to solve this coz i m very badly stuck here :(

Would be really very helpful.

Comment: Please only include screenshots when you don't have any other options. Your first two examples are things that could easily have been copy-pasted. By showing an image, you are actively making it more difficult because people then have to re-type what is in the photo to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `node_modules/.bin/` part, your npm script you just be

```
"babel_script": "babel src/index.js -W -o ..."
```

Comment: yaa this works .... Thanks a lot but one more little question when i cancel the terminal by ctrl + c it then stops that script. What if i have to use some more commands below this script without letting it stop??

Comment: is this because of the  -w  flag??

Comment: You should post a new question for that.